# Getting nil pointer error when trying to start a unstartedServer from httptest

Tags: go

I am trying to build a mock httpserver in my code. I want to specify the port number so I have used the below code:

```
l, _ := net.Listen("http", "localhost:49219")
svr := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { ... }))
svr.Listener.Close()
svr.Listener = l
svr.Start()
```

However, at line svr.Start(), I am getting an error saying:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Obviously svr is not nil at that point. I am wondering why I am getting this error and how should I fix this?

Comment: Ok package `net` provides portable interface for network I/O, including
TCP/IP, UDP, domain name resolution, and Unix domain sockets. Because of that your Listner is not getting created for `http` and when you call `.Start()` it throws an issue. You can change this to `net.Listen("tcp", "49219")` and it will work, Otherwise you can use the httpServer and routing and use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to update first argument when you are calling `net.Listen` function ( Line:  `l, := net.Listen("http", "localhost:49219")`.
- It must be `tcp`, `tcp4`, `tcp6`, `unix` or `unixpacket` instead of `http`.
- For `IPv4`, you can use `tcp4`.

**Example:**

```golang
l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", "localhost:49219")
if err != nil {
  // handle error here
}
svr := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { ... }))
svr.Listener.Close()
svr.Listener = l
svr.Start()
```